# htaccess: how to redirect all URLs with a percent sign after a slash to 404?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, percent-encoding

I already tried some Rewrite Rules but none of them worked out:

```
RewriteRule ^example/%(.*)$ - [R=404,L,NC,B]
RewriteRule ^example/\%(.*)$ - [R=404,L,NC,B]
RewriteRule ^example/%(.*)$ - [R=404,L,NC]
```

What is the correct syntax for that purpose?

*Edit:*
It's not redirecting to my 404 page, instead it gives me an Error 400. How could that be?

Comment: http://www.example.com/example/%blabla and something is happening, sorry I forgot to mention. But it returns an Error 400 and it's not redirecting as expected to my 404 Page...

Comment: Yes it is because `%b` is not a valid character and not allowed by your Apache. `mod_rewrite` will not be even invoked for this.

Comment: Thx for that info! So there is nothing I can do about it? It seems not even ErrorDocument 400 /404.php return 404 when that error occurs....

Comment: Yes these requests are blocked by Apache for security reasons without invoking your .htaccess

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you very much!!! :)